# how do i make matrix list numbers 1-something

Tags: python, math

```py
y = int(input())
z = y * y
matrix=[[]]
matrix = [[z for x in range(y)] for x in range(y)]
for a in matrix:
    ln = ""
    for i in a:
        ln += str(i) + " "
    print(ln)
```

so far I have this and if I input 3 it returns:

```
9 9 9 
9 9 9
9 9 9
```

how do I make it return 1-9 instead

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please note that we don't solve homework exercises. What have you tried to do? Where are you blocked/

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac this isn't a homework exercise I am just trying to learn python but I find it kind of difficult to understand

Comment: You have now completely changed the question from it's original form.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac I have indeed changed the question but the output I was looking for is still the same I started over and rephrased my question but the goal is still the same

Comment: No, this is totally different. The only common thing is that you want to print a matrix of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you always put `z` in the matrix:

```
matrix = [[z for x in range(y)] for x in range(y)]
```

`z` is constant (`z = y * y`), which is why you get a matrix full of `9`.

If you want to count, you can replace `z` with a proper index. And also choose two separately named iterator variables. Otherwise, they will hide each other:

```
matrix = [[i + y * j for i in range(y)] for j in range(y)]
```